# Best way to determine if function call was successful

Tags: string, replace, vbscript, registry

Consider the following VBScript sample, which reads a value from the registry and converts a relative path string into an absolute path string:

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strPath = Replace(objShell.RegRead(someRegKey),"\relative path","\\?\Absolute path",1,-1,1)
```

What's the best way to determine if the call to `RegRead()` succeeded?  I know that `RegRead()` will raise an `Err` if the registry key does not exist.

- In VBScript, does the entire line get skipped if an `Err` is raised, or will the inner call return a NULL or some undefined value to the outer `Replace()` function?
- If it's the latter, will the `Replace()` function also raise an error or will it merely return a NULL or whatever?
- Will `Err.Number` be the fail code from the `RegRead()` call or the `Replace()` call?
- What will the value of `strPath` be?  Would it be an empty string, unmodified, or would it be undefined?
- What's the best way to test for an empty string?  Are `If strPath = ""` and `IsEmpty(strPath)` equivalent statements?

Basically, if I use this construct in a VBScript, is it safe to simply check the value of `Err.Number`? Or do I need to test the resultant string? Or both?

I'm trying to not be overly verbose in my code, but in a broader sense I want to understand how VBScript handles these things.

Comment: The entire line will be skipped, there is nothing from stopping you from breaking the line down into manageable chunks and only using the `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` check on the `objShell.RegRead(someRegKey)`. However consider using [@Ansgar's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33726042/692942) for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to not use `RegRead` (or nested function/method calls) in the first place. Use WMI (which will provide you with an actual return code) and separate the registry read from the replacement operation:

```
Const HKCU = &H80000001
Const HKLM = &H80000002

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

hive = HKLM
key  = "SOFTWARE\foo"
valueName = "bar"

rc = reg.GetStringValue(hive, key, valueName, value)

If rc <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Error reading " & key & "\" & valueName & ": " & rc
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

strPath = Replace(value, "\relative path", "\\?\Absolute path", 1, -1, 1)
```